# OpenPop.net called from unmanaged code (causing GPF)

Tags: unmanaged

I would like to create a C# managed x86 DLL wrapper for OpenPop that I call from my unmanaged (C) code.

I have done this for other products in the past using the NuGet "UnmanagedExports" package which seems to work well.

I tried doing this with the OpenPop.net package but I get a GPF as soon as I call "client = new Pop3Client();". If I remove all calls to OpenPop, the DLL loads and returns properly.

Furthermore, I am accessing OpenPop from within a try/catch structure yet it still fails with a GPF (instead of catching this error).

I installed the latest OpenPop.net package v2.0.6.1120 and I am targeting .net v4.5.2 (I also tried v4.0 with no difference).

Can OpenPop.net be used like this in conjunction with the UnmanagedExports package? If so, any suggestions on how I might debug this?

Thank you!

(I realize that this is free software so support is no expected so I am more than happy to pay for support if required)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... I was not copying the OpenPop.dll to my application folder where my DLL is loaded. Once the file was available, the GPF no longer occurred. Too bad this was not able to be trapped by the C# exception handler.